# Unknown job error on gunicorn upstart job

Tags: django, ubuntu, nginx, gunicorn, ubuntu-16.04

I am getting the error **start: Unknown job: bifrost.conf** when I use the command *sudo start gunicorn.bifrost.conf*.

My conf file is as follows:

```
description "Gunicorn server for bifrost"

start on net-device-up
stop on shutdown

respawn

chdir /home/ubuntu/sites/bifrost/source

exec ../virtualenv/bin/gunicorn --bind unix:/tmp/bifrost.socket Bifrost.wsgi:application
```

Also my nginx config looks like this.

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /static {
        alias /home/ubuntu/sites/bifrost/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/bifrost.socket;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try [this](http://mwhiteley.com/scripts/2012/12/11/dbus-init-checkconf.html) to check your config file.

Comment: I am not familiar with dbus. But, I am getting **check-conf.sh: line 19: /bin/dbus-daemon: No such file or directory**

Comment: Is it possible that because of the dot as part of the filename?